# PHP - Create table use STR_PAD

Tags: php, html-table

Example php like this

```php
        for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
            $i = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $url = $i."<br />";
            echo $url;
        }
```

I want output use table :

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        01<br>
        02<br>
    </td>
    <td>
        03<br>
        04<br>
    </td>
    <td>
        05<br>
        06<br>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for everybody who can help me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Using modulus `%`, you can check if the value is even/odd, and open/close the table cell.

```
//open the table
echo '<table><tr>';

 for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){

    // if odd start cell
    if($i % 2 != 0) echo '<td>';

            $i = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $url = $i."<br />";
            echo $url;

    //if even close the cell
    if($i % 2 == 0) echo '</td>';
        }

// Close the table      
echo '</tr></table>';
```

---

**edit**
If you want the cell break to occur after 50, then you would can the modulus to `50` using `$i % 50 == 1` and `$i % 50 == 0`

```
//open the table
echo "<table><tr>";

 for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++){

    // if odd start cell
    if($i % 50 == 1) echo "<td>";

            $i = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $url = $i."<br />";
            echo $url;

    //if even close the cell
    if($i % 50 == 0) echo "</td>";
        }

// Close the table      
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: that's the most beautiful thing i've ever seen; thanks for sharing it!

Comment: if me change the output like this : `<table><tr><td>01<br>02<br> //--until-- 49<br>50<br></td><td>51<br>52<br> //--until-- 99<br>100<br></td></tr></table>`,what i change?

Comment: so you want the cell change to happen every 50? if so, I have edited my answer with how to use `$i % 50 == 1`/`$i % 50 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

If you know you'll always be outputting in pairs...

```
# i personally prefer sprintf over str_pad.  But if you don't,
# you only have one place to have to change it.
$format = function($x) { return sprintf('%02d', $x); };

# write out each pair.  Note the $i+=2.
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i+=2) {
    $first = $format($i);
    $second = $format($i+1);
    echo "<td>{$first}<br>{$second}<br></td>";
}
```